# Probability of points in a triangle

Tags: probability, geometry

$O(2,3)$, $A(2,0)$, $B\left(1,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ are the vertices of $\Delta{OAB}$ on the $\text{x-y}$ plane. Let $\text{R}$ be the region

consisting of all points $P$ inside the triangle, which satisfy:
$$d(P,OA)\geq \min\{d(P,OB), d(P,AB)\} $$

For a random distribution of point P, the probability that it lies in the region $\text{R}$ is of the form: $a-b\sqrt[c]{d}$

$\text{Find:}d^{a}+ c^{b}$$$$$
$d(X,YZ)$ is defined as the perpendicular distance of point (X) on the line $YZ$.

Could somebody be so kind as to please tell me how to answer this? I would indeed be very grateful to you. Thanks so much!

Comment: (This was reposted as I don't know how to request people to please answer my doubt. If this offends anybody, please tell me I shall delete this at once.)

Comment: You already posted this. What have you tried in between? Have you checked the problem? Did you try the proposed solution?

Comment: Sir, I asked if there was any error repeatedly even after outlining your method, but was still informed that the coordinates were correct.
Then I tried to find similar questions on the Net. I confess I gave up for a while after that.
Then throughout the afternoon, I've been trying to understand why it should be the incenter, but was unable to understand why. Could you please tell me why the incenter is taken? Thanks a lot for your efforts!

Comment: The incenter is the locus which is at equal distance to all sides. it divides the triangle into three other smaller triangle, each part corresponding to an area where the point is closest to the corresponding side.

Comment: Alright Sir, thanks a lot!

Comment: [https://brilliant.org/problems/probabilistic-geometrical-distribution/](https://brilliant.org/problems/probabilistic-geometrical-distribution/).

Comment: Alright Sir. It's just that the aforementioned question still does not have any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to compute where the incenter of $OAB$ lies, since the locus of points $P$ for which $d(P,OA)=d(P,OB)$ is the internal angle bisector through $O$, for instance.